# How would I build this JSON using a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am exporting line items from a woocommerce store and need to send the data via an API in JSON format. I have an array for the simpler part of this JSON example however I am lost at this part as I am unfamiliar with the JSON objects and how to build this as an array.

Example JSON:

```
"bundles": [{
            "type": "TYPE1",
            "items": [{
                "bom": [{
                        "type": "C",
                        "stockId": "1",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "metadata": {
                            "key": "value"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "E",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "stockId": "2"
                    }
                ]
            }],
            "delivery": {
                "method": "FIRST_CLASS_ROYAL_MAIL",
                "shippingAddress": {
                    "firstname": "value",
                    "lastname": "value",
                    "addressLine1": "value",
                    "addressLine2": "value",
                    "town": "value",
                    "county": "value",
                    "postcode": "value"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "TYPE2",
            "items": [{
                "bom": [{
                        "type": "C",
                        "stockId": "4",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "metadata": {
                            "key": "value",
                            "key": "value"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }],
            "delivery": {
                "method": "E",
                "key": "value",
                "key": "value"
            }
        }
    ]
```

My current PHP so far for another part of this same object:

```
$postData = array(
    's' => array(
        'n' => 'T',
        'k' => '5'
    ),
    'c' => array(
        'n' => 'C',
        'e' => 'c'
    ),
    'p' => array(
        'p' => 'S',
        't' => 't',
        'a' => '8',
        'c' => '8'
    )
);
```

Is the above built as a standard php array and it will format correctly when doing JSON encode?

Comment: Do you want to convert it to PHP array? if so: `$json = json_decode("your json string here");var_dump($json);`

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. This is an example of what I need to send via an API. I need to build the same JSON object using PHP.

Comment: Yes you can use php **associative array** and after that usw **json_encode(array_here)** function

Comment: json_encode() and json_decode() are your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I know is to json encode an array like this:

```
<?php

echo json_encode(
    [
        "bundles" =>[ [
            "type" => "TYPE1",
            "items" => [
                [
                    "bom" => [
                        [
                            "type" => "C",
                            "stockId" => "1",
                            "quantity" => 1,
                            "metadata" => [
                                "key" => "value"
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            "type" => "E",
                            "quantity" => 1,
                            "stockId" => "2"
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            "delivery" => [
                "method" => "FIRST_CLASS_ROYAL_MAIL",
                "shippingAddress" => [
                    "firstname" => "value",
                    "lastname" => "value",
                    "addressLine1" => "value",
                    "addressLine2" => "value",
                    "town" => "value",
                    "county" => "value",
                    "postcode" => "value"
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            "type" => "TYPE2",
            "items" => [
                [
                    "bom" => [
                        [
                            "type" => "C",
                            "stockId" => "4",
                            "quantity" => 1,
                            "metadata" => [
                                "key" => "value",
                                "key" => "value"
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]],
                "delivery" => [
                    "method" => "E",
                    "key" => "value",
                    "key" => "value"
                ]
            ]]
        ]
    );
```

That returns

> {"bundles":[{"type":"TYPE1","items":[{"bom":[{"type":"C","stockId":"1","quantity":1,"metadata":{"key":"value"}},{"type":"E","quantity":1,"stockId":"2"}]}],"delivery":{"method":"FIRST_CLASS_ROYAL_MAIL","shippingAddress":{"firstname":"value","lastname":"value","addressLine1":"value","addressLine2":"value","town":"value","county":"value","postcode":"value"}}},{"type":"TYPE2","items":[{"bom":[{"type":"C","stockId":"4","quantity":1,"metadata":{"key":"value"}}]}],"delivery":{"method":"E","key":"value"}}]}

That is exactly your json ...

Comment: That's perfect thank you. I needed to see the PHP version of my JSON. Is there a reason for the use of square brackets?

Comment: I just noticed in the returned JSON it reads {"bundles":{ whereas in the code I posted it is "bundes":[{. Why is there no square bracket within the response yours got?

Comment: @BenH, my code is PHP. Starting from version 5.4 (released 5 years ago) is available short syntax array. In version 5.4.0 short array syntax has been added, e.g. $a = [1, 2, 3, 4]; or $a = ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'four' => 4];.

Comment: The response looks slightly off. In the JSON posted in my question "bundles" is followed by [{ whereas in your response it is only followed by a single {. If you 'beautify' it you will see the difference

Comment: Now is ok for you?

Comment: Ahh yes! That makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have one example you can check this to solve your problem code as below.

$jsonArray=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
if (!empty($jsonArray)) {

```
foreach ($jsonArray->workers as $key => $value) 
{
    $workers_ins="insert into workers_mst (workers_name,date,apply_id,active_flag,crt_date) values ('".$value->workers_name."','".$value->date."','".$apply_id."','1','".time()."')";
    mysqli_query($con,$workers_ins) or throw_error(mysqli_error($con));
}
```

}

Comment: What are you doing? O_o

Comment: random answer ?  random code ? the suspense is killing me

Comment: I honestly have no clue how that would of be of help?